# What's the fastest way to get an ObjectContext reference from an entity object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, objectcontext, entityobject

I'm creating extensions for my EntityFramework objects as described in [How to: Customize Generated Data Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738696.aspx) but in some of those extensions I need to get the instance's ObjectContext to look up some other values in the model. I've found [Tip 24 – How to get the ObjectContext from an Entity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx) but that was written a couple years ago, which is referenced in this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516340/how-to-get-a-reference-to-superior-object-from-entity-object) but I'm really hoping there's a better answer now.

Surely this must be something that's needed frequently enough that retrieval of an Entity's object context from the entity itself should be supported with an official method.

Thanks in advance for any more recent information on this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution, using [connected properties](http://connectedproperties.codeplex.com/).

Using connected properties would look like this (warning: untested code):

```
public partial class Database1Entities
{
    private struct ObjectContextProperty { }

    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.ObjectMaterialized += (_, e) =>
        {
            e.Entity.GetConnectedProperty<Database1Entities, ObjectContextProperty>().Set(this);
        };
        this.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (_, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add)
            {
                e.Element.GetConnectedProperty<Database1Entities, ObjectContextProperty>().Set(this);
            }
            else if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Remove)
            {
                e.Element.GetConnectedProperty<Database1Entities, ObjectContextProperty>().Set(null);
            }
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object context for the entity. Returns <c>null</c> if the entity is detached.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity for which to return the object context.</param>
    public static Database1Entities FromEntity(EntityObject entity)
    {
        return entity.GetConnectedProperty<Database1Entities, ObjectContextProperty>().GetOrConnect(null);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Database1Entities.FromEntity` to get the object context from an entity object. You can also define an actual property on the entity objects as well if you want:

```
public partial class Table1
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets the object context for this entity. Returns <c>null</c> if the entity is detached.
    /// </summary> 
    public Database1Entities ObjectContext { get { return Database1Entities.FromEntity(this); } }
}
```

In this solution, the `ObjectContext` property on the entity objects is optional.

Comment: thanks. I'll look into connected properties a bit and see if that makes sense for this project. I appreciate your time in answering this question.

Comment: Good work, Also you can use extension methods to add a method such as GetObjectContext to all entityObjects.

public static Database1Entities GetObjectContext(this EntityObject entityObject)
        {
            return Database1Entities.FromEntity(entityObject);
        }

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any such method. The described workaround looks like the only option because the entity is derived from `EntityObject` which is defined as:

```
[Serializable, DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public abstract class EntityObject : StructuralObject, IEntityWithKey,  
    IEntityWithChangeTracker, IEntityWithRelationships
{
    ...
}
```

As I know only `IEntityWithRelationships.RelationshipManager` leads to `ObjectContext`. This wasn't changed in EF 4.

Also it is not really common to access the context from the entity. I can imagine that this can be helpful in case of implementing Active Record Pattern on top of EF but in such case you would also have probably control over creating the context inside the static method of the entity so you should be able to set it to the entity. In other cases I would say that it is something you should avoid as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your definitive reply, Ladislav. I must disagree with your assertion "it is something you should avoid as much as possible". Clearly, there is a need for this, or the questions and posts on how to do it would never have been written. There's a way to get a reference to the ObjectContext for most entity instances, but it's inefficient. There are many valid scenarios where retrieving the context of an object from the object itself is desired, in particular with extension methods that require data-related operations not currently supported by Entity Framework models.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use; it's a convention-based approach that is simple to add to a project.

First, add hooks to your object context:

```
public partial class Database1Entities
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.ObjectMaterialized += (_, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic entity = e.Entity;
                entity.ObjectContext = this;
            }
            catch (RuntimeBinderException)
            {
            }
        };
        this.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (_, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add)
            {
                try
                {
                    dynamic entity = e.Element;
                    entity.ObjectContext = this;
                }
                catch (RuntimeBinderException)
                {
                }
            }
            else if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Remove)
            {
                try
                {
                    dynamic entity = e.Element;
                    entity.ObjectContext = null;
                }
                catch (RuntimeBinderException)
                {
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This will attempt to dynamically set a property called `ObjectContext` on any entity that is associated with the object context.

Next, add an `ObjectContext` to the entity types:

```
public partial class Table1
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets or sets the context for this entity.
    /// This should not be set by end-user code; this property will be set
    /// automatically as entities are created or added,
    /// and will be set to <c>null</c> as entities are detached.
    /// </summary> 
    public Database1Entities ObjectContext { get; set; }
}
```

This solution does require an `ObjectContext` property to be added to each entity type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Stephen. Unfortunately, adding this property to each entity type is simply not feasible or sustainable.

Comment: @John: In that case, see my other answer using connected properties.